# NgbModel ERROR TypeError: "this._modalStack is undefined"

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm having this issue where the property _modalStack of the NgbModal service is undefined when using this service in another service, this is the service I am using the NgbModal:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { LoggerService } from '@app/shared/logger.service';
import {
  NgbModalOptions,
  NgbModal,
  NgbModalRef,
} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { ErrorHandlingModalComponent } from '@app/error-handling-modal/error-handling-modal.component';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ErrorService {
  constructor(private modal: NgbModal, private loggerService: LoggerService) {
  }
  // Errors
  handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse): Observable<never> {
    this.showModal(error.status);
    return this.loggerService.handleError(error);
  }

  public showModal(code: number) {
    if ([401, 403, 500].includes(code)) {
      console.log(this.modal);
      const ngbModalOptions: NgbModalOptions = {
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: false,
      };
      const modalRef = this.modal.open(
        ErrorHandlingModalComponent,
        ngbModalOptions
      );
      this.updateModal(code, modalRef);
    }
  }

  public updateModal(code: number, modal: NgbModalRef) {...nothing important here...}
```

The funny thing is that when I use the same logic of `showModal(...)` in a component, it works! not sure why it does not for this service..

This is the error I am getting in the console:

[image]

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: in the source code, I see `_modalStack` is injected into the `NgbModal`. I guess it could be some error happening during the creation of `NgbModal`. Do you see maybe some errors in the console during the app startup?

Comment: this happens pretty much when the app starts..